# Compute Variance per Period in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a set of data that looks like the following:

```
team runs_scored       date
LAN           3        2014-03-22
ARI           1        2014-03-22
LAN           7        2014-03-23
ARI           5        2014-03-23
LAN           1        2014-03-30
SDN           3        2014-03-30
```

I'm trying to test a predictive model on this set and one of the input parameters is the variance of `runs_scored` in t-1. In other words, to predict the outcome variable for the 4th observation, I need the variance of `LAN` based on the prior observations in the dataset.

I can compute cumulative means and sums, but I can't quite figure out how to compute the cumulative variance in the data set. I'm doing most of my data manipulation in `dplyr`, but I'm not opposed to using an alternative solution if it gets me what I need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writing out variance formula as, `(sum(x^2)-length(x)*mean(x)^2)/(length(x)-1)`, you see  that it can be easily generalized to cumulative variances, just by replacing each functions in it by its cumulative versions(`cummean` is from `dplyr`). So,

```
library(dplyr)
cum_var <- function(x){
    n <- 1:length(x)
    (cumsum(x^2)-n*cummean(x)^2)/(n-1)
}
```

And speed comparison to @MrFlick's `cumvar` seems encouraging.

```
x <- rnorm(1e6)
all.equal(cum_var(x), cumvar(x))
#[1] TRUE
system.time(cumvar(x))[3]
elapsed 
   5.52 
system.time(cum_var(x))[3]
elapsed 
   0.04
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a cumulative variance, you could implement the [online-algorithm for variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm). The main benefit is that it scales linearly rather than exponential as it would if you iterated over all the possible subsets.

If you have

```
x<-c(3,1,7,5,1,3)
```

You can do

```
cumvar<-function(x) {
   tail(Reduce(local({mm<-0; nn<-0; function(a,b) 
        {nn<<-nn+1; d<-b-mm; mm<<-mm+d/nn; a+d*(b-mm)}}), 
        x, 0, accumulate=TRUE), -1)/(seq_along(x)-1)
}
cumvar(x)
# [1]       NaN 24.500000 14.333333 10.000000  7.700000  6.166667  5.333333   4.696429  4.111111  3.777778
```

Which returns the same result as

```
cumvar2 <- function(x)  {
    sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) var(x[1:i]))
}
cumvar2(x)
# [1]        NA 24.500000 14.333333 10.000000  7.700000  6.166667  5.333333  4.696429  4.111111  3.777778
```

And we can compare efficiencies with

```
set.seed(15)
x<-rpois(100, 5)
microbenchmark:::microbenchmark(cumvar(x), cumvar2(x))

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   cumvar(x)  272.502  297.2425  335.2058  315.490  339.625  957.728   100  a 
#  cumvar2(x) 1672.323 1793.0960 2089.8104 1865.838 1956.208 6386.863   100   b
```

But if you want to use this algorithm, I suggest you read the wiki page if you're only calculating variance one, then the two-pass method is more robust.

You could use it with `dplyr` with

```
dd<-read.table(text="team runs_scored       date
LAN           3        2014-03-22
ARI           1        2014-03-22
LAN           7        2014-03-23
ARI           5        2014-03-23
LAN           1        2014-03-30
SDN           3        2014-03-30", header=T)

dd %>% mutate(cvar=lag(cumvar(runs_scored)))

#   team runs_scored       date     cvar
# 1  LAN           3 2014-03-22       NA
# 2  ARI           1 2014-03-22      NaN
# 3  LAN           7 2014-03-23 2.000000
# 4  ARI           5 2014-03-23 9.333333
# 5  LAN           1 2014-03-30 6.666667
# 6  SDN           3 2014-03-30 6.800000
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a large dataset? If for loops aren't too slow, you can just do this:

```
data$vars <- NA
for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
  data$vars[i] <- var(data$runs_scored[1:(i - 1)])
}
```

this gives

```
  team runs_scored      date     vars
1  LAN           3 3/22/2014       NA
2  ARI           1 3/22/2014       NA
3  LAN           7 3/23/2014 2.000000
4  ARI           5 3/23/2014 9.333333
5  LAN           1 3/30/2014 6.666667
6  SDN           3 3/30/2014 6.800000
```

edit: if you want to do it slightly faster, you can write a specific function for this application:

```
data$vars <- NA
cumVar <- function(position, df){
  return(var(data$runs_scored[1:(position - 1)]))
}
```

Then use sapply to apply the function and get a vector out:

```
position <- 3:nrow(data)
results <- c(NA,NA, sapply(position, cumVar,data))
data$var <- results
```

On my machine, for about 30000 rows, for the for loop, it took about 10.5 seconds, and with sapply, about 7.5 seconds.