# Cumulative Calculations (e.g. cumulative correlation) with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

In R, I have a data.table with two measurements `red` and `green` and would like to calculate their cumulative correlation.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(red   = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6.5, 7.6, 8.7),
                 green = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12,  14,  16),
                 id    = 1:8)
```

How can I get the following output within one data.table command?

```
...
> DT[1:5, cor(red, green)]
[1] 1                     # should go into row 5
> DT[1:6, cor(red, green)]
[1] 0.9970501             # should go into row 6, and so on ...
> DT[1:7, cor(red, green)]
[1] 0.9976889
```

**Edit:**
I am aware that it can be solved by looping, but my data.table has about 1 million rows grouped into smaller chunks, so looping is rather slow and I thought there might be some other possibility.

Comment: How big is the data.table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on my answer to the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28758406/3573401) for cumulative variances, you can find cumulative covariances as

```
library(dplyr) # for cummean
cum_cov <- function(x, y){
  n <- 1:length(x)
  res <- cumsum(x*y) - cummean(x)*cumsum(y) - cummean(y)*cumsum(x) + n*cummean(x)*cummean(y)
  res / (n-1)
}

cum_var <- function(x){# copy-pasted from previous answer
    n <- 1:length(x)
    (cumsum(x^2) - n*cummean(x)^2) / (n-1)
}
```

Cumulated correlation is then

```
cum_cor <- function(x, y) cum_cov(x, y)/sqrt(cum_var(x)*cum_var(y))
DT[, cumcor:=cum_cor(red, green),]
   red green id    cumcor
1: 1.0     2  1       NaN
2: 2.0     4  2 1.0000000
3: 3.0     6  3 1.0000000
4: 4.0     8  4 1.0000000
5: 5.0    10  5 1.0000000
6: 6.5    12  6 0.9970501
7: 7.6    14  7 0.9976889
8: 8.7    16  8 0.9983762
```

I hope it is fast enough

```
x <- rnorm(1e6)
y <- rnorm(1e6)+x
system.time(cum_cor(x, y))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.319   0.020   0.339
```

Comment: Oh, this one is still a bit faster, as it builds on the primitive functions directly. The answer from Michele is good as well for the general approach, I think.

Comment: If speed is not the issue, good old `for loop` is always your friend.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a `cumcor` function?

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(red   = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6.5, 7.6, 8.7),
                 green = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12,  14,  16),
                 id    = 1:8)

cumcor <- function(x, y, start = 5, ...) {
    c(rep(NA, start - 1), sapply(start:length(x), function(k) cor(x[1:k], y[1:k]), ...))
}

DT[, list(red, green, cumcor = cumcor(red, green))]
   red green    cumcor
1: 1.0     2        NA
2: 2.0     4        NA
3: 3.0     6        NA
4: 4.0     8        NA
5: 5.0    10 1.0000000
6: 6.5    12 0.9970501
7: 7.6    14 0.9976889
8: 8.7    16 0.9983762
```

Please mind the above `cumcor` function would require more QC at the beginning (`x` and `y` having same length, `start` being greater than 0, etc.)

Comment: Thank you - the easy solution is often the best (like cumsum() vs. sum()). I originally had hoped for something data.table-internal (with these .N and shift() - operators), but this works pretty good and is very readable and clear.