# Expanding window (cumulative calculation) in data.table: how to improve performance

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I have grouped data collected at different time steps. Within each time step, there are several registrations of values. Each value may occur one or more times within and among time steps.

### Some toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(grp = rep(1:2, each = 8),
                 time = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(3, 3)),
                 val = c(1, 2, 1,  2, 3,  2, 3, 4,  1, 2, 3,  1, 1,  1, 2, 3))

df
#    grp time val
# 1    1    1   1
# 2    1    1   2
# 3    1    1   1
# 4    1    2   2
# 5    1    2   3
# 6    1    3   2
# 7    1    3   3
# 8    1    3   4
# 9    2    1   1
# 10   2    1   2
# 11   2    1   3
# 12   2    2   1
# 13   2    2   1
# 14   2    3   1
# 15   2    3   2
# 16   2    3   3
```

### Objectives

I wish to do some calculations within an expanding time window, i.e. within time step 1, within time 1 and 2 together, within 1, 2, and 3 together, and so on. Within each window, I wish to calculate the number of unique values, the number of values which have occurred more than once, and the proportion of values which have occurred more than once.

For example, in my toy data, in group (grp) 1, in the second time window (time = 1 & 2 together) three unique values (val 1, 2, 3) have been registered (n_val = 3). Two of them (1, 2) occur more than once (n_re = 2), resulting in a "re_rate" of 0.67 (see below).

My data.table code produces the desired result. On a small data set it is slower than my `base` attempt, which I believe is fair enough, given some possible overhead in the data.table code. With a larger data set, the `data.table` code catches up, but is still slower. I expected (hoped) that the benefits would show up earlier.

Thus, what made me post this question is that I believe that **the *relative* performance of my code is a strong indicator of me abusing data.table** (I am sure the reason is *not* data.table performance itself). Thus, the main objective of my question is to get some advice on **how to code this in a more data.table-esque way**. For example, is it possible to avoid the loop over time windows altogether by vectorizing the calculations, as shown e.g. in the nice answer by @Khashaa [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221695/cumulative-calculations-e-g-cumulative-correlation-with-data-table-in-r). If not, are there ways to make the loop and assignment more efficient?

---

### My `data.table` code:

```
library(data.table)

f_dt <- function(df){
  setDT(df, key = c("grp", "time", "val"))[ , {
  # key or not only affects speed marginally

    # unique time steps
    times <- .SD[ , unique(time)]

    # index vector to loop over
    idx <- seq_along(times)

    # pre-allocate data table
    d2 <- data.table(time = times,
                     n_val = integer(1),
                     n_re = integer(1),
                     re_rate = numeric(1))

    # loop to generate expanding window
    for(i in idx){

      # number of registrations per val
      n <- .SD[time %in% times[seq_len(i)], .(n = .N), by = val][ , n]

      # number of unique val
      set(x = d2, i = i, j = 2L, length(n))

      # number of val registered more than once
      set(x = d2, i = i, j = 3L, sum(n > 1))
    }
    # proportion values registered more than once
    d2[ , re_rate := round(n_re / n_val, 2)]
    d2
  }
  , by = grp]
}
```

...which gives the desired result:

```
f_dt(df)

#    grp time n_val n_re re_rate
# 1:   1    1     2    1    0.50
# 2:   1    2     3    2    0.67
# 3:   1    3     4    3    0.75
# 4:   2    1     3    0    0.00
# 5:   2    2     3    1    0.33
# 6:   2    3     3    3    1.00
```

---

### Corresponding `base` code:

```
f_by <- function(df){
  do.call(rbind,
          by(data = df, df$grp, function(d){

            times <- unique(d$time)
            idx <- seq_along(times)
            d2 <- data.frame(grp = d$grp[1],
                             time = times,
                             n_val = integer(1),
                             n_re = integer(1),
                             re_rate = numeric(1))

            for(i in idx){

              dat <- d[d$time %in% times[seq_len(i)], ]
              tt <- table(dat$val)
              n_re <- sum(tt > 1)
              n_val <- length(tt)
              re_rate <- round(n_re / n_val, 2)

              d2[i, ] <- data.frame(d2$grp[1], time = times[i], n_val, n_re, re_rate)
            }
            d2
          })
  )
}
```

---

### Timings:

Tiny toy data from above:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f_by(df),
               f_dt(df),
               times = 10,
               unit = "relative")

# Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f_by(df) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
# f_dt(df) 1.481724 1.450203 1.474037 1.452887 1.521378 1.502686    10
```

Some larger data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE),
                 time = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE),
                 val = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE))

microbenchmark(f_by(df),
               f_dt(df),
               times = 10,
               unit = "relative")

# Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# f_by(df) 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
# f_dt(df) 1.094424 1.099642 1.107821 1.096997 1.097693 1.194983    10
```

No, the data is still not *large*, but I would expect data.table to catch up by now. If coded properly... I believe this suggests that there is a large potential for improvement of my code. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f <- function(df){
  setDT(df)[, n_val := cumsum(!duplicated(val)), grp
   ][, occ := 1:.N, .(grp, val)
     ][, occ1 := cumsum(occ == 1) - cumsum(occ == 2), grp
       ][, n_re := n_val - occ1,
         ][, re_rate := round(n_re/n_val, 2),
           ][, .(n_val = n_val[.N], n_re = n_re[.N], re_rate =re_rate[.N]), .(grp, time)]
}
```

where

- `cumsum(!duplicated(val))` counts the (cumulative) occurrences  of the unique values, `n_val`,
- `occ` counts the cumulative occurrences each value (note that it is grouped by `val`).
- `occ1` then counts the number of elements in `val` occurred only once so far.
  The number of values occurred only once increases by 1 when `occ==1`, decreases by 1 when `occ==2`; hence `cumsum(occ == 1) - cumsum(occ == 2)`.
- The number of values which have occurred more than once is `n_val-occ1`

**Speed Comparison**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(grp = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE),
                 time = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE),
                 val = sample(1:100, 100000, replace = TRUE))


system.time(f(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.038   0.000   0.038 

system.time(f_dt(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 16.617   0.013  16.727

system.time(f_by(df))
# user  system elapsed 
# 16.077   0.040  16.122
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Khashaa When looking for an answer to my question, I read your nice answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221695/cumulative-calculations-e-g-cumulative-correlation-with-data-table-in-r). (I have updated my question with a link to that Q&A, sorry for not including it from the start). It's really cool that you managed to avoid a loop also in your answer here. To be honest, I didn't dare to hope for such a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for a better way to code expanding window of non-duplicated groups and came across this question.

This question seems to be more about expanding window where the group (i.e. time in the question) is duplicated. Below is a solution making use of `between`.

```
#expanding group by where groups are duplicated
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , {
        #get list of unique time groups to be used in the expanding group
        uniqt <- unique(time)

        c(list(time=uniqt), #output time as well

            #expanding window of each unique time group
            do.call(rbind, lapply(uniqt, function(n) {

                #tabulate the occurrences
                x <- table(val[between(time, uniqt[1L], n)])

                #calculate desired values
                n_val <- length(x)
                n_re <- sum(x > 1)
                data.frame(n_val=n_val, n_re=n_re, re_rate=n_re/n_val)
        })))

    }, by=grp]
```

result:

```
#    grp time n_val n_re   re_rate
# 1:   1    1     2    1 0.5000000
# 2:   1    2     3    2 0.6666667
# 3:   1    3     4    3 0.7500000
# 4:   2    1     3    0 0.0000000
# 5:   2    2     3    1 0.3333333
# 6:   2    3     3    3 1.0000000
```

I was unable to find in which version of `data.table` was `between` first released and hence, `between` might be released after this question was posted.