# Cumulative (expanding window) mean by group with duplicate check for each calculation

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculating a mean over an expanding window, however the data structure makes it so that previous answers are missing at least a little bit of what's needed (closest is here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135899/expanding-window-cumulative-calculation-in-data-table-how-to-improve-performa)).

My data looks something like:

```
  Company TimePeriod IndividualID Date.Indiv.Acted  Value 
1  1         2015          A           2015-01-01    400
2  1         2015          B           2015-02-01    200
3  1         2015          A           2015-06-15    400
4  1         2015          C           2015-07-12    300
5  1         2016          A           2016-07-15    400
6  1         2016          B           2016-08-09    100
7  1         2016          C           2016-09-10    400
8  1         2016          A           2016-10-11    100
9  2         2004          A           2004-07-12    200
10 2         2004          B           2004-08-12    300
```

And I need to take the cumulative mean of the Value, by Company-TimePeriod, for each Date.Indiv.Acted. However, I need to remove duplicates as I go along keeping the most recent one. So for the first two averages, there's no problem - they would include row 1, and row 1 and row 2. However, row 1, 2, and 3 should remove row 1 because IndividualID is a duplicate. Essentially, I have forecast information and want to use only the most recent forecast by an individual in each calculation of the mean.

So my final data would look something like (rows added for ease of interpretation - don't need that in the data),

```
  Company TimePeriod IndividualID Date.Indiv.Acted  Value CumMean 
1  1         2015          A           2015-01-01    400   400
2  1         2015          B           2015-02-01    200   300 (row 1 and 2)
3  1         2015          A           2015-06-15    400   300 (row 2 and 3)
4  1         2015          C           2015-07-12    300   300 (2,3,4)
5  1         2016          A           2016-07-15    400   400 (5)
6  1         2016          B           2016-08-09    100   250 (5,6)
7  1         2016          C           2016-09-10    400   300 (5,6,7)
8  1         2016          A           2016-10-11    100   200 (6,7,8)
9  2         2004          A           2004-07-12    200   200 (9)
10 2         2004          B           2004-08-12    300   250 (9,10)
```

A data.table solution would be ideal, but I'm not picky as long as it can run on fairly large data (20M rows or so) and not take until the heat death of the universe.

Any help you guys have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your data is divergent. The first table you show us has different information. E.g. Line 2 has `Value=400` in the first table and `Value = 200` in the second

Comment: Oh gosh haha - I have no idea how that happened - I thought I just copied and pasted it twice and made the edits. Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setDT(dt)
dt[, occ := 1:.N, by = .(Company, TimePeriod, IndividualID)]
dt[, n := cumsum(!duplicated(IndividualID)), by = .(Company, TimePeriod)]
dt[, Value1 := Value,]
dt[, x := c(0, diff(Value)), by = .(Company, TimePeriod, IndividualID)]
dt[occ>1, Value1 := x,]
dt[, Cummean := cumsum(Value1)/n, by = .(Company, TimePeriod)]
dt[, c("occ", "n", "Value1", "x") := NULL][]
#    Company TimePeriod IndividualID Date.Indiv.Acted Value Cummean
# 1:       1       2015            A       2015-01-01   400     400
# 2:       1       2015            B       2015-02-01   200     300
# 3:       1       2015            A       2015-06-15   400     300
# 4:       1       2015            C       2015-07-12   300     300
# 5:       1       2016            A       2016-07-15   400     400
# 6:       1       2016            B       2016-08-09   100     250
# 7:       1       2016            C       2016-09-10   400     300
# 8:       1       2016            A       2016-10-11   100     200
# 9:       2       2004            A       2004-07-12   200     200
#10:       2       2004            B       2004-08-12   300     250

dt <- structure(list(Company = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), TimePeriod = c(2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2004, 2004), IndividualID = c("A", 
"B", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), Date.Indiv.Acted = c("2015-01-01", 
"2015-02-01", "2015-06-15", "2015-07-12", "2016-07-15", "2016-08-09", 
"2016-09-10", "2016-10-11", "2004-07-12", "2004-08-12"), Value = c(400, 
200, 400, 300, 400, 100, 400, 100, 200, 300)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ha - That's a really clever answer and perfectly addresses my immediate concern. Thanks! As an aside, this doesn't appear to be extendable to a median case or a variance case (given you're reducing the subsequent events by the value of the previous one, not removing the value entirely) of those values. Is there a clean way to approach those problems using a similar idea?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Rats. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I particularly do not like loops, but I think this one got simple enough to understand the step by step. It can be easily altered to run any other metric instead of mean (e.g. cumulative variance)

```
# function that drops duplicates and calculates cumulative mean
fun.attempt <- function(dat, dup, value){
  #dat: data set
  #dup: string column to look for duplicates
  #value: string column to calculate the mean

  x <- dat[!duplicated(get(dup), fromLast = T), .(get(value))]

  y <- cumsum(x) / 1:nrow(x)

  y <- y[nrow(y)]
  return(y)
}

foo[, grp := .GRP, by = .(Company, TimePeriod)] # to create a more efficient loop
hl <- list() # as storage

for(k in unique(foo$grp)){

    got <- foo[grp == k] # running the cumulative mean for each grouping

    for(y in 1:nrow(got)){
      # applying customized function
      got[y, cummean2:= fun.attempt(got[1:y], 'IndividualID', 'Value')]

    }

    hl[[k]] <- got # storing the subsetted data.tables

}
```

Now just compile the lists of data.tables. `CumMean` column is your original calculation, `cummean2` is mine.

```
rbindlist(hl)
    Company TimePeriod IndividualID Date.Indiv.Acted Value CumMean grp cummean2
 1:       1       2015            A       2015-01-01   400     400   1      400
 2:       1       2015            B       2015-02-01   200     300   1      300
 3:       1       2015            A       2015-06-15   400     300   1      300
 4:       1       2015            C       2015-07-12   300     300   1      300
 5:       1       2016            A       2016-07-15   400     400   2      400
 6:       1       2016            B       2016-08-09   100     250   2      250
 7:       1       2016            C       2016-09-10   400     300   2      300
 8:       1       2016            A       2016-10-11   100     200   2      200
 9:       2       2004            A       2004-07-12   200     200   3      200
10:       2       2004            B       2004-08-12   300     250   3      250
```

Comment: While a little slower than pure data.table code, this lets me calculate the variance and median of the data in addition to just the mean, so I really appreciate you taking the time to answer!